# How can I undelete `empty recycle` file(s) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I accidentally deleted files and emptied the trash bin. :(

Now I want to un-delete those files. Is it possible?

Comment: As William Hilsum said, stop using the computer.  When you delete files, windows just deletes the "map" to them but the data does not get "deleted".  But it will eventually get over written by files so stop everything until you get your files back!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, stop using the machine - the more you use, the less likely you will be able to recover files.

Download and extract Recuva **Portable** to a USB or some sort of storage - http://www.piriform.com/recuva/builds and then run it on the machine.

Do the advanced mode and try to find the files you need.

Recuva is easy and simple to use, if you need a more advanced solution and don't mind paying, take a look at [R-Studio](http://www.r-studio.com/)